# How to get Mesos Marathon Stdout from App Creation Command?

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

If I create a new app using Marathon UI with a bad command e.g. "badcommand" there's no stdout/stderr associated with the task (in Marathon UI or Mesos UI). How do a get that stdout/stderr?

I included the Marathon log below, but it just says that the task (test2) failed. The stdout works fine for me with Docker containers. I did see some info in the [docs](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/logging/), but nothing that addressed this.

For my actual use case I'm trying to run a bash script to create some database tables. Obviously I could just create a Dockerfile that extends the existing one, but running the script from Marathon would be easier because if I create my own Dockerfile with sensitive information than I have to pay for the private hosting instead of using the free Docker Hub service.

```
I0210 17:07:12.341120     9 slave.cpp:4999] Launching executor test2.ba02dba1-d018-11e5-87cd-02420a013102 of framework 379ed26c-465f-4b0f-90f9-d058ad6d028b-0000 with resources cpus(*):0.1; mem(*):32 in work directory '/tmp/mesos/slaves/379ed26c-465f-4b0f-90f9-d058ad6d028b-S0/frameworks/379ed26c-465f-4b0f-90f9-d058ad6d028b-0000/executors/test2.ba02dba1-d018-11e5-87cd-02420a013102/runs/ef4db108-dce3-45f6-b273-11db38289e24'
I0210 17:07:12.341696     8 docker.cpp:735] No container info found, skipping launch
I0210 17:07:12.341958     9 slave.cpp:1628] Queuing task 'test2.ba02dba1-d018-11e5-87cd-02420a013102' for executor 'test2.ba02dba1-d018-11e5-87cd-02420a013102' of framework 379ed26c-465f-4b0f-90f9-d058ad6d028b-0000
E0210 17:07:12.342250     9 slave.cpp:3466] Container 'ef4db108-dce3-45f6-b273-11db38289e24' for executor 'test2.ba02dba1-d018-11e5-87cd-02420a013102' of framework 379ed26c-465f-4b0f-90f9-d058ad6d028b-0000 failed to start: None of the enabled containerizers (docker) could create a container for the provided TaskInfo/ExecutorInfo message
E0210 17:07:12.343215     9 slave.cpp:3537] Termination of executor 'test2.ba02dba1-d018-11e5-87cd-02420a013102' of framework 379ed26c-465f-4b0f-90f9-d058ad6d028b-0000 failed: Unknown container: ef4db108-dce3-45f6-b273-11db38289e24
I0210 17:07:12.343487     9 slave.cpp:2762] Handling status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 02327ed1-3b62-47ae-860a-29a055df99a6) for task test2.ba02dba1-d018-11e5-87cd-02420a013102 of framework 379ed26c-465f-4b0f-90f9-d058ad6d028b-0000 from @0.0.0.0:0
W0210 17:07:12.343763    11 docker.cpp:998] Ignoring updating unknown container: ef4db108-dce3-45f6-b273-11db38289e24
I0210 17:07:12.344077    10 status_update_manager.cpp:322] Received status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 02327ed1-3b62-47ae-860a-29a055df99a6) for task test2.ba02dba1-d018-11e5-87cd-02420a013102 of framework 379ed26c-465f-4b0f-90f9-d058ad6d028b-0000
I0210 17:07:12.344272    10 status_update_manager.cpp:826] Checkpointing UPDATE for status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 02327ed1-3b62-47ae-860a-29a055df99a6) for task test2.ba02dba1-d018-11e5-87cd-02420a013102 of framework 379ed26c-465f-4b0f-90f9-d058ad6d028b-0000
I0210 17:07:12.369632    10 slave.cpp:3087] Forwarding the update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 02327ed1-3b62-47ae-860a-29a055df99a6) for task test2.ba02dba1-d018-11e5-87cd-02420a013102 of framework 379ed26c-465f-4b0f-90f9-d058ad6d028b-0000 to master@192.168.8.101:5050
I0210 17:07:12.382553     8 status_update_manager.cpp:394] Received status update acknowledgement (UUID: 02327ed1-3b62-47ae-860a-29a055df99a6) for task test2.ba02dba1-d018-11e5-87cd-02420a013102 of framework 379ed26c-465f-4b0f-90f9-d058ad6d028b-0000
I0210 17:07:12.382820     8 status_update_manager.cpp:826] Checkpointing ACK for status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 02327ed1-3b62-47ae-860a-29a055df99a6) for task test2.ba02dba1-d018-11e5-87cd-02420a013102 of framework 379ed26c-465f-4b0f-90f9-d058ad6d028b-0000
I0210 17:07:12.414659     8 slave.cpp:3657] Cleaning up executor 'test2.ba02dba1-d018-11e5-87cd-02420a013102' of framework 379ed26c-465f-4b0f-90f9-d058ad6d028b-0000
```

Comment: Why don't you set the private information as environment parameters when you start the Docker image via Marathon...?

Comment: I should have clarified - I consider my schema and permissions "private" so we're talking about dozens of commands. Regardless this still seems like an issue with Marathon if I can't see the output of commands.

Comment: Well, you could mount your scripts via a volume to the container. It's not really clear to me how exactly you want to run the scripts from Marathon... Using a JDBC connection? And where do you get the driver from? Furthermore, you can host your private registry within your Mesos cluster via https://hub.docker.com/r/_/registry/